# Knockout binding with multiple values for each option in select

Tags: html, forms, knockout.js

In a form I have a select box with several options, each representing a report with various variables which influence the rest of the form. Some reports require a start date, others an end date, some require both. I have bound the requirements for each of the reports to the option-elements like this:

```
<select data-bind="value: ReportId">
    <option value="ID" data-hasStartDate="BOOL" data-hasEndDate="BOOL">Report name</option>
</select>

<input data-bind="visible: hasStartDate" />
<input data-bind="visible: hasEndDate" />
```

with ID being the id of the report and BOOL being either true or false. I use knockout to data-bind the value of the select-box to the reportId. But I could not figure out how to bind the hasStartDate and hasEndDate-values to a Knockout observable in order to show the appropriate form elements.

Even with custom bindings, I needed a normal jQuery onChange-event in order to apply the values to the Knockout-values hasStartDate and hasEndDate. Is it possible to do it entirely with Knockout itself?

Comment: Your data should be in the viewmodel, not the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the [options binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) for select boxes?

You also can't bind knockout using `data-whatever="some value"`. You always use **data-bind**, like so: `data-bind="bindingtype: value"`.

**Edit:**
That being said... If you want to get the data from a selected option in a `<select>` element, I would use the following jQuery:

```
$("select").on('change', function() {
   var selectedData = $(this).find(":selected").data("stuff");
});
```

You can then use selectedData and apply this to a knockout view model.

Working example in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RZq6Q/4/

Comment: The reason I don't use the options binding is because I do not have the objects represented in the select-box as a knockout-array. The select box gets generated with ASP.NET MVC 3.

I use the data-whatever properties to store the values, but not for data-binding. I was hoping there was some way to read out and apply those values to the Knockout-model in a Knockout function.

Comment: If you are building a knockout app, I would strongly recommend gathering all your view data in knockout, and not mix ASP.NET MVC views and knockout views in this way.

Comment: It's true that it's better to have as much as possible in the views, but i'm having views with lots of static content which gets loaded quicker when it's build using MVC, instead of generated through Javascript with Knockout. So I was trying to find a right balance between both, but that might not always result in the most elegant solution.

Comment: I understand. Will update my answer to help you with what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, so I reckon it is not possible without jQuery event handling then, as was my initial question :) I'll accept that as an answer. So to do it with Knockout and get rid of such events and selectors, I need to use another approach (create a non-recursive object representation and convert that to knockout in order to use options-binding).

Comment: Well, it could be used with normal JavaScript event handling of course, jQuery just makes it simpler. I think you could also build a Knockout custom binding and apply that to your select/options in some way, but that's possibly overkill depending on how much work you want to do.. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html